# Count all subordinates who directly or indirectly reports to managers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got a problem with one task.

I need to count all subordinates (distinct) who directly or indirectly reports to a specific manager

I have an `Employee` table like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID Int,
MANAGER_ID Int,
EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200)
```

Example:

```
            Alex(1)
    --------------------
    Jhon(2)          Kevin(3)
------------------------------
Mike(4) Amanda(5)  Tom(6) Jery(7)
```

I can count only employee who directly reports to a manager:

```
SELECT 
    MANAGER_ID
   ,COUNT(MANAGER_ID) as SubCount
FROM [dbo].[EMPLOYEE]
GROUP BY MANAGER_ID
```

But in result I have something like this:

```
Manager_ID | SubCount
----------------------
1          | 2
2          | 2
3          | 2
----------------------
```

Instead:

```
Manager_ID | SubCount
----------------------
1          | 6
2          | 2
3          | 2
----------------------
```

I will be happy for any suggestions or idea how to do this.

Comment: The usual approach would be to start writing some TSQL....

Comment: What kind of DB server are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @t table(EMPLOYEE_ID Int,
MANAGER_ID Int,
EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200))
insert @t values(1,null,'Alex'),(2,1,'Jhon'),(3,1,'Kevin'),
(4,2,'Mike'),(5,2,'Amanda'),(6,3,'Tom'),(7,3,'Jerry')

;with a as
(
select EMPLOYEE_ID boss,EMPLOYEE_ID from @t t
  where exists (select 1 from @t where t.EMPLOYEE_ID = MANAGER_ID)
union all
select a.boss, t.EMPLOYEE_ID
from @t t join a on t.MANAGER_ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
)
--subtracting 1 because it is also counting the manager
select boss, count(*)-1 SubCount from a group by boss
option (maxrecursion 20)
```

Comment: It's works perfect with a small amount of people (like in this example) but I can't get any results from my tabel where I have around 1000 employee_id's and around 20 people have subordinates with max level=4. I got "Executing query ..." message for 1 hour already. Can you suggest me something to resolve this problem? It's looks like we a very close to  completion.

Comment: @user1523087 this will be quite fast with that few employees(1000), your problem is that you have a recursive issue: person 1 points to person 2 who points to person 3 who points back to person 1 - making this an endless loop. I would lover the maxrecursion to 20 and fix the data

Comment: Thank you. You suppose was right about "person 1 points to person 2 who points to person 3 who points back to person 1". That was my problem. Fixed it and now everything workы perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with managers as (
      select employee_id, manager_id, 1 as level
      from employees e
      union all
      select e.employee_id, m.manager_id, e.level+1
      from managers m join
           employees e
           on m.manager_id = e.employee_id
     )
select m.manager_id, count(*)
from managers m
group by m.manager_id;
```

The recursive CTE creates all employee/manager pairs.  The final query does the aggregation and counting.

EDIT:

It sounds like there are cycles in the employee/manager relationship.  I think the following fixes this (I don't have SQL Server available right now to test it):

```
with managers as (
      select employee_id, manager_id, 1 as level
      from employees e
      union all
      select e.employee_id, m.manager_id, e.level+1
      from managers m join
           employees e
           on m.manager_id = e.employee_id
      where e.employee_id not in (select employee_id from managers)
     )
select m.manager_id, count(*)
from managers m
group by m.manager_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried to run this query, I got an error like this: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: @user1523087 Add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the bottom of the query - 100 is default number of max recursion for CTEs, but it can be changed with this command (0 stands for unlimited)

Comment: @NenadZivkovic hardly a good idea here, if 100 isn't enough, there is clearly something else wrong as max recursion will be 3 in this example

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes, ofcourse, if run on this sample, 3 is enough. I thought perhaps this error came from some other (real) data. Haven't really checked the query, but you are right it seems something else is wrong.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I doubt any company in the world has 100 lairs of managers :)

Comment: Mistake is in the recursive part SELECT - should be `e.manager_id` instead of `m.manager_id` and `m.level+1` instead of `e.level+1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34224/discussion-between-t-clausen-dk-and-nenad-zivkovic)